# Как увеличить лимит данных в new Map()

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я пишу парсер, в строке проверяется один параметр на наличие в (let data = new Map()), но я столкнулся с лимитом примерно в "16777216". (Парсит около 50кк строк.)
Допустим:

```js
let data = new Map();

for (let i = 0; i < 50000000; i++)
{
    try
    {
        data.set(i, true);
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        console.log(`i = ${i}`, e);
        break;
    }
}
```

Я нашел класс BigMap, но воспользовавшись им у меня уже вылезла другая ошибка:
"FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"

Как мне увеличить лимит или что еще можно придумать?

[UPD]
Немного изменилась задача по данным. Есть строка:
"Параметр 1:Параметр 2"
Нужно что-бы у "параметр 1", не повторялся "параметр 2", то есть..
Такую строки оно должно пропустить и занести все значения:
"Что-то:Значение 1"
"Что-то:Значение 2"
А у таких только первая строка пройдет, т.к. такое значение уже есть:
"Что-то:Значение 1"
"Что-то:Значение 1"

Это что-то типо:

```
let data = new Map();
// ...
let params1 = 'Что-то';
let params2 = 'Значение 1';

let values = data.get(params1);

if (data.has(params1) && values.lastIndexOf(params2) !== -1)
{
// bad
return;
}

data.set(params1, [params2, ...values]);
```

Репозиторий: https://bitbucket.org/Oliver_Patterson/parser/src

Comment: создайте воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Добавил в первый пост.

Comment: Чтобы парсить строки в таком количество логичнее всего разделить их на чанки и каждый из них обрабатывать, очевидно что у вас просто не хватает памяти для решения задачи.

Comment: Можно более подробно? Я "немного" не разбираюсь в ноде и в целом в JS, понимаю ее, но не так чтобы много опыта было.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54466812/1016033
«V8 developer here. I can confirm that 2^24 is the maximum number of entries in a Map»

Но кажется, если вам нужно столько ключей, вам стоит пересмотреть алгорит

Comment: Я находил статью про лимит, и в нем же про BigMap.
Я в первом посте описал как изменилась задача.

Comment: а сколько в вашем файле строк?

Comment: Больше 50.000.000.

Comment: @OliverPatterson и данные из этого файла только парсятся и считаются уникальные/дубликаты? уникальные строки потом нигде никак не применяются?

Comment: Строки: "Тест:Значение 1", "Тест:Значение 2", "Тест:Значение 1", "Что-то новое:Значение 1". Должны добавиться в другой файл строки "Тест:Значение 1", "Тест:Значение 2", "Что-то новое:Значение 1".

Comment: Мне кажется, что проще загнать эти данные в базу данных

Comment: @OliverPatterson то есть считать файл, немного изменить и записать в другой файл уникальные данные?

Comment: Смотря что вы имеете ввиду под "изменить".

Comment: под "изменить" я имею ввиду вот [это](https://bitbucket.org/Oliver_Patterson/parser/src/520993bd6e40812b78a5e20581c2ce1ebec76d16/renderer/js/main.js#lines-68)

Comment: Да, немного изменить и записать в другой файл.

Comment: а какая средняя длина строки?

Comment: Где-то 20 символов, но встречаются строки по 40 символов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, ваша проблема не в размере входных данных (размере файла или строки), а в размере промежуточной структуры данных, по которой вы проверяете наличие повторяющихся строк.

Можно попробовать создание нескольких `Map` в массиве: при достижении лимита ключей создавать новый подраздел, а проверять сразу по всем разделам в массиве.

Только нужно учесть, что по умолчанию Node.js имеет лимит в 2 GB памяти. Когда я тестировал свой пример ниже, создавая ключи-числа и присваивая им `true`, как в вашем примере, мне этой памяти хватило. Но как только я стал использовать ключи-строки и присваивать им такие же числа, памяти уже не хватило. Увеличить память можно так (число означает мегабайты):

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 test.mjs
```

Возможно, это поможет вам решить проблему с BigMap, если мой вариант с несколькими Map вам не подойдёт.

Запускайте этот пример в браузерах с осторожностью, я не знаю, какой где лимит памяти и что будет, если его исчерпать в разных браузерах:

```js
const mapKeysLimit = 2 ** 24;
const data = [new Map()];

for (let i = 0; i < 50000000; i++) {
  let currentMap = data[data.length - 1];
  if (currentMap.size === mapKeysLimit) {
    currentMap = new Map();
    data.push(currentMap);
    console.log(`New map when i = ${i}.`);
  }
  currentMap.set(`${i}`, i);
}

console.log(data.map(map => map.size));

function checkInMaps(maps, key) {
  return maps.some(map => map.has(key));
}

function findInMaps(maps, key) {
  for (const map of maps) {
    const value = map.get(key);
    if (value !== undefined) return value;
  }
  return undefined;
}

console.log(checkInMaps(data, '1'));
console.log(findInMaps(data, '1'));

console.log(checkInMaps(data, '50000001'));
console.log(findInMaps(data, '50000001'));
```

Вывод у меня в Node.js:

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 test.mjs

New map when i = 16777216.
New map when i = 33554432.
[ 16777216, 16777216, 16445568 ]
true
1
false
undefined
```

Comment: но почему Map, а не Set? суть же - проверка уникальности

Comment: или вообще, посчитать checksum и искать в чем-то типа btree

Comment: Насколько я понял, там одновременно проверка по ключам и значениям: нужно сначала создать уникальный ключ, потом в значении ключа создать массив и туда заносить только уникальные значения.

Comment: Кстати, вот вместо этого массива в значении ключа как раз Set подойдёт лучше, раз значения должны быть там уникальны.

Comment: я предполагал в Set пихать key+(U+0000)+val. но пока поставил на эксперимент просто заполнить set рандомом по 400байт. upd: мне кажется плохой идеей поиск по одному Set на 50кк записей. а вот с твоим предложением, да если выполнять поиски параллельно во всех «коллекциях», - ок

Comment: Я думаю 4гб схватит с головой для 50кк строк (25кк смогло с 2гб обработать, на 45кк не хватило, а дальше не стал эксперементировать). Только у меня теперь вопрос, как мне указать эти 4гб, если я использую electron, то есть.. Чтобы я мог собрать и использовалось 4гб?

Comment: Я давно electron-ом не пользовался и не знаю, как сейчас собирают там проекты. Попробуйте погуглить "max-old-space-size electron". Может, что-то вроде этого вам поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933951/how-to-increase-the-max-memory-limit-for-the-app-built-by-electron-builder

Comment: Я выделил сначала 4, потом 8гб, программа все равно падает. 30кк смогло пропарсить. У программы пропадает вся HTML часть, остается только белый квадратик (у окна скрыт frame). Мне кажется тут уже не дело не только в памяти. **По итогу: Всем спасибо за помощь, это все же самый рабочий вариант (наверное не считая БД, не решился начать изучать).**

Comment: А зачем вам Electron для этой задачи? Или сама задача только часть приложения с обязательным GUI?

Comment: о, кстати, я поресёрчил. тут sqlite хорошо зашёл без всяких танцов с бубном вокруг памяти приложения. и электрон её любит. завтра, наверное, опубликую ответ (неделя была ппц)

Answer (score 1):

Решение этой задачи с использованием встраиваемой базы данных [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) для хранения уникальных пар.

Такое решение не требует костылей увеличения размера доступной памяти и более перспективно, если приложение получит дальнейшее развитие - работать с базой данных проще, чем при каждом запуске приложения заново считывать в память огромный массив данных.

---

Сначала я написал скрипт для генерации тестового набора данных, он сгенерирует 60 миллионов пар с дубликатами:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');

const fd = fs.openSync(`${__dirname}/data.txt`, 'w+');
for (const str of generate(20000000)) {
  fs.appendFileSync(fd, str);
  fs.appendFileSync(fd, '\r\n');
}
fs.fsyncSync(fd);
for (const str of generate(20000000)) {
  fs.appendFileSync(fd, str);
  fs.appendFileSync(fd, '\r\n');
}
fs.fsyncSync(fd);
for (const str of generate(20000000)) {
  fs.appendFileSync(fd, str);
  fs.appendFileSync(fd, '\r\n');
}
fs.closeSync(fd);


/**
 * @param { number } size
 * @returns { string[] }
 */
function generate(size = 50 * 1000 * 1000) {
  let array = [];
  while (array.length < size) {
    const key = crypto.randomBytes(randomNumber(14, 25))
      .toString('base64').replace(/={1,}$/, '');

    for (let i = 0; i < randomNumber(3, 5); i++) {
      const value = crypto.randomBytes(randomNumber(4, 8)).toString('base64');
      const line = `${key}: ${value}`;
      array.push(line);
      if (i % 2 !== 0) {
        array.push(line);
      }
    }
    if (array.length >= 1000000 && array.length % 1000000 < 10) {
      console.log(array.length);
    }
  }
  array = shuffle(array);
  return array;
}

/**
 * @param {number} [min=0]
 * @param {number} [max]
 * @returns {number}
 */
function randomNumber(min = 0, max) {
  if (max === null || max === undefined) {
    max = min; min = 0;
  }
  return Math.trunc(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

/**
 * @param { any[] } array
 * @returns { any[] }
 */
function shuffle(array) {
  let currentIndex = array.length;
  let temporaryValue;
  let randomIndex;

  while (currentIndex !== 0) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
```

```bsh
$ node --max-old-space-size=7168 src/stream-big-data-1/generator/index.js
```

Чтобы понять время выполнения кода, предложенного [@vsemozhebuty](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/321883/vsemozhebuty) в принятом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1236760/2659), пишу подходящий для этого скрипт:

```js
// @ts-check
/**
 * --max_old_space_size=4096
 */
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const readline = require('readline');

const mapKeysLimit = 2 ** 24;
const storage = [new Map()];

(async () => {
  const filepath = path.join(__dirname, 'generator', 'data.txt');
  const res = await handleFile(filepath);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
  console.log(`Время выполнения скрипта: ${formatDate(res.time)}`);
})();

/**
 * @param {string} filepath
 * @returns {Promise<{
 *   lines: number;
 *   doubles: number;
 *   uniq_keys: number;
 *   uniq_pairs: number;
 *   time: number;
 * }>}
 */
async function handleFile(filepath) {
  const timeBegin = Date.now();

  const result = {
    lines: 0,
    doubles: 0,
    uniq_keys: 0,
    uniq_pairs: 0,
  };

  const stream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: stream,
    output: process.stdout,
    crlfDelay: Infinity,
    terminal: false,
  });

  for await (const line of rl) {
    if (line !== undefined && line !== null) {
      result.lines++;

      let currentMap = storage[storage.length - 1];
      if (currentMap.size === mapKeysLimit) {
        storage.push(currentMap = new Map());
      }

      const [key, value] = line.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(/: /);

      const uniqK = !checkKeyInStorage(key);
      result.uniq_keys += +uniqK;
      const uniqP = !checkPairInStorage(key, value);
      result.uniq_pairs += +uniqP;

      if (uniqP) {
        currentMap.set(key, value);
      } else {
        result.doubles++;
      }
    }
    if (result.lines % 1000000 === 0) {
      console.log(`[lines: ${result.lines}]    скрипт выполняется: ${formatDate(Date.now() - timeBegin)}`);
    }
  }

  rl.close();

  return { ...result, time: (Date.now() - timeBegin) };
}

/**
 * @param {string} key
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function checkKeyInStorage(key) {
  return storage.some((map) => map.has(key));
}

/**
 * @param {string} key
 * @param {string} value
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function checkPairInStorage(key, value) {
  for (const map of storage) {
    if (value === map.get(key)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

/**
 * @param {number} ms
 * @returns {string}
 */
function formatDate(ms) {
  const n = ms % 1000;
  const seconds = Math.trunc(ms / 1000);
  const h = Math.trunc(seconds / 3600);
  const s = seconds % 60;
  const m = ((seconds - s) % 3600) / 60;

  const str = [`${h}`.padStart(2, '0'), `${m}`.padStart(2, '0'), `${s}`.padStart(2, '0')].join(':');

  return `${str}.${`${n}`.padEnd(3, '0')}`;
}
```

```bsh
$ node --max_old_space_size=4096 index-array.js
{
  "lines": 60000006,
  "doubles": 6998914,
  "uniq_keys": 11999063,
  "uniq_pairs": 53001092,
}
Время выполнения скрипта: 00:04:35.870
```

Теперь мой вариант решения с использованием sqlite3, для ускорения всё делается максимально "в лоб" - все пары вставляются в БД, а затем подсчитывается стата:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const readline = require('readline');
const Database = require('better-sqlite3');

const db = new Database(':memory:');

db.unsafeMode();
db.pragma('synchronous = off');
db.pragma('journal_mode = off');
db.pragma('auto_vacuum = NONE');
db.pragma('page_size = 8192');
db.pragma('cache_size = 10000');
db.exec('CREATE TABLE pairs (key VARCHAR(255), value VARCHAR(255))');

const stmtPairInsert = db.prepare('INSERT INTO pairs (key, value) values (?, ?)');

(async () => {
  db.exec('BEGIN TRANSACTION');

  const filepath = path.join(__dirname, 'generator', 'data.txt');
  const res = await handleFile(filepath);

  db.exec('END TRANSACTION');

  console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
  console.log(`Время выполнения скрипта: ${formatDate(res.time)}`);

  db.close();
})();

/**
 * @param {string} filepath
 * @returns {Promise<{lines: number; doubles: number; uniq_keys: number; uniq_pairs: number; time: number; }>}
 */
async function handleFile(filepath) {
  const timeBegin = Date.now();

  const result = {
    lines: 0,
    doubles: 0,
    uniq_keys: 0,
    uniq_pairs: 0,
  };

  const stream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: stream,
    output: process.stdout,
    crlfDelay: Infinity,
    terminal: false,
  });

  for await (const line of rl) {
    if (line !== undefined && line !== null) {
      result.lines++;
      handleLine(line);
    }
    if (result.lines % 1000000 === 0) {
      console.log(`[lines: ${result.lines}]    скрипт выполняется: ${formatDate(Date.now() - timeBegin)}`);
    }
  }

  rl.close();

  result.uniq_keys = db.prepare('select count(*) as n from (select 1 from pairs group by key)').get()?.n || 0;
  result.uniq_pairs = db.prepare('select count(*) as n from (select 1 from pairs group by key, value)').get()?.n || 0;
  result.doubles = result.lines - result.uniq_pairs;

  return { ...result, time: (Date.now() - timeBegin) };
}

/**
 * @param {string} line
 * @returns {void}
 */
function handleLine(line) {
  const [key, value] = line.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(/: /);
  stmtPairInsert.run(key, value);
}

/**
 * @param {number} ms
 * @returns {string}
 */
function formatDate(ms) {
  const n = ms % 1000;
  const seconds = Math.trunc(ms / 1000);
  const h = Math.trunc(seconds / 3600);
  const s = seconds % 60;
  const m = ((seconds - s) % 3600) / 60;

  const str = [`${h}`.padStart(2, '0'), `${m}`.padStart(2, '0'), `${s}`.padStart(2, '0')].join(':');

  return `${str}.${`${n}`.padEnd(3, '0')}`;
}
```

```bsh
$ node node index-better-sqlite3.alt.js
{
  "lines": 60000006,
  "doubles": 6998914,
  "uniq_keys": 11999063,
  "uniq_pairs": 53001092,
}
Время выполнения скрипта: 00:10:50.502
```

[Чуть более интеллектуальная работа с данными](https://github.com/norbornen/stackoverflow-practice/blob/main/src/stream-big-data-1/index-better-sqlite3.js) увеличит время работы программы до 15 минут, но это - нормально, если смотреть в перспективе.

---

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но как я увидел, это заняло час, а это довольно много.

Comment: @OliverPatterson мне не давала покоя такая разница во времени выполнения, так что [поресёчил](https://github.com/norbornen/stackoverflow-practice/tree/main/src/stream-big-data-1) и переписал код =) осталось попробовать ещё in-memory berkley db, но, чует моё сердце, не будет существенного ускорения