# Как убрать лимит на количество ключей у объекта javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Сейчас при добавлении 48 млн ключей в объект asMap код зависает, ошибок не выдает.
Можно ли как то убрать ограничение чтобы можно было добавлять и миллиарды ключей?

```
let cicles = 0;
const asMap = {};

result.map((item) => {
    const k_ = Object.keys(item);
    let str = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < k_.length; i++) {
      str += `${item[k_[i]]}_`;
      cicles++;
    }
  
    asMap[str] = item;
    if(cicles % 100000 === 0){
      console.log('result3 map cicles='+cicles);
    }
  });
```

Уточняю вопрос:

Что нужно сделать, чтобы добавление нескольких миллионов ключей в обычный объект javascript не приводило к зависанию nodejs процесса? Без использования других конструкций. Вопрос конкретно про объект который создаётся через инструкцию

```
   let asMap = {};
```

Comment: Если вам нужны миллиарды ключей в JS — у вас фатальная ошибка в выборе архитектуры (и, возможно, языка).

Comment: Ну вот вам тикет. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=11852
В JS нет лимитов, а в движках есть. Живите с этим.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1236760/2659 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1247751/2659

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как увеличить лимит данных в new Map()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1236585/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-new-map)

Comment: _Очевидно, что нет каких либо ограничений по потреблению оперативной памяти._ - если только размер твоих объектов не превышает лимит. Ты проверил сколько в итоге занимает процесс nodejs? Пробовал ли ты дожидаться окончания? Почему ты думаешь, что именно зависло, а не просто долго выполняется?

Comment: @manking, вероятно разработчики справедливо считают, что ради общего блага (как его понимают они, а не вы) подобные запросы требуют уже других средств для их решения (например, СУБД). Поймите, обычно ресурсы компьютера должны справедливо делиться среди множества параллельно исполняющихся независимых задач. А ваша лишь одна из них.

Comment: @avp Это понятно. Но есть сервис который 10 лет на продуктиве крутится и  несколько отделов от него зависят, и никто не даст его переделывать или изменять это очень дорого и требует согласования огромного количества документации. Поэтому подобные предложения являются оффтопом, и не несут практической ценности в данной конкретной теме. 

При нехватке памяти выводятся ошибки или контейнер перезагружается. А тут ровно когда ключей становится где то 48000000 впадает в спячку и через 10 часов находится в том же состоянии. А при использовании Map он может хранить свыше 48 млн ключей.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131437/discussion-on-question-by-manking--------).

Answer (score 3):

Сделай по аналогии с гитом:

```js
map = Object.create(null);
...
(map[key.slice(0, 2)] ??= Object.create(null))[key] = smth;
```