# JS. Предел количества элементов Set

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть такой код:
***(осторожно с запуском, тк очень много вычислений)***

```js
const arr = []
const set = new Set()

const count = 100_000_000
let isEnded = false

for (let i = 0; i < count && !isEnded; i++) {
  try {
    const id = generateUniqId()
    arr.push(id)
    set.add(id)
  } catch (e) {
    isEnded = true
    console.log(`Ошибка на ${i} итерации`)
  }
}

console.log('Количество элементов:', arr.length);
console.log('Set элементов:', set.size);

function generateUniqId() {
  return Math.random()
}
```

Принцип работы:
Наполняет `arr` и `set` *100_000_000* (ста миллионами) элементов
Но во время выполнения, постоянно ошибка при добавлении в `set` 16777217-го элемента:

```
RangeError: Value undefined out of range for undefined options property undefined
```

Из за чего это может быть?
Нигде раньше не встречал в описании Set-а, что его размер ограничен

Если ограничения есть, то в чём?
В кол-ве элементов, или байтовом размере или что-то другое?

Comment: почитайте обсуждения в этом вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1236585/2659

Answer (score 4):

Это проблема движка V8, вот тикет на их баг трекере. Судя из комментариев исправлять эту проблему не собираются. В FF данной проблемы нету.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=11852

Comment: у меня в FF ошибка на 44 миллионе повторений

Comment: у меня код автора в FF отрабатывает успешно https://i.imgur.com/6qsC0n5.png

Comment: https://skr.sh/sDHzReYYnem Возможно проблема в железе компа

Comment: @ЕвгенийКулик, ради интереса проверил еще на рабочем ноуте и на дедикейтед сервере. Цикл отработал успешно. Интересный вопрос с очень разными мнениями...

Answer (score 1):

скорей всего, вы превышаете квоту на ячейку памяти в JS в 16МБ

дело не в Set, потому что, если убрать его из кода, код будет ломаться и страница просто не отвечает.

`Math.random()` выдает число в таком виде `0.4092814434418963`, каждая цифра в этом числе занимает байт, если округлить `Math.random()`, то ваш код отлично работает

в таком случае каждое сгенерированное число занимает меньше места в памяти

```js
const arr = []
const count = 100_000_000
let set = new Set()
let isEnded = false

for (let i = 0; i < count && !isEnded; i++) {
    try {
        const id = generateUniqId()
        arr.push(id)
        set.add(id)
    } catch (e) {
        isEnded = true
        console.log(`Ошибка на ${i} итерации`)
    }
}

console.log('Количество элементов:', arr.length);
console.log('Set элементов:', set.size);

function generateUniqId() {
    return Math.random().toFixed(2)
}
```

Comment: Количество попарно различных строк, генерируемых конструкцией `Math.random().toFixed(2)` не превосходит `101`: от `0.00` до `1.00`. Не удивительно, что все они помещаются в `Set`.

Comment: @wololo согласен, маленько не то я сделал, при `Math.random().toFixed(6)` ошибка происходит опять на добавлении `16777217` элемента в `Set`, хотя итеррация цикла больше `18 000 000`, значит `array` принял в себя больше количество элементов, значит есть ограничение по байтам именно у Set, я так понимаю это

Comment: Но если убрать `Set` из скрипта, то цикл все равно не дойдет до конца, страница просто ломается и все, значит проблемы там не только в `Set`